# Migrating all of Wordpress website into one

Tags: database, wordpress, migrating

Currently, i have 3 WooCommerce Wordpress websites. However, i want to migrating them into new one (Users, Pages, Posts, Products,...).

I have tried to export and import individually each of section above.

There is one problem : The Pages, Posts, Products are not associated with the correct Users Id anymore. The users Id is changed in the database because of migrating.

Is there any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

U can use cimy users manager.

1. Download & Install Cimy Users Manager
2. In users -> cimy users manager, scroll down and click export button.
3. Download the data and go to new    wordpress site, like number 2. Select the data and click import.

After users imported in new site, now export one by one posts, pages by authors.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand is the following thing, you have 3 website and want to unify them to a new one.

What i recommend you is to find a “sync content” plugin, the only one that i know is only for multi site wordpress.  [Link here](https://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-multisite-posts-pages-and-custom-post-types-sync/20143748?s_rank=1) if that doesnt work, try migrating the content from database directly or manually.